# Dell Inspiron 5150 with wifi issue

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

The subject laptop has a minipci card in it used for wireless connection. It worked well under XP Pro, but since formatting the disk, installing 12.04, and installing the drivers it still does not see the wireless signal. I have learned that Dell used Dell Quickset utility to turn on/off the card. Is there an alternative for ubuntu that can be used?

Comment: Check this this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access

Answer (score 1):

> The results of running: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` were:
>
> ```
> 02:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g wireless LAN  Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 02)
> ```
>
> The driver needed was b43legacy. Performed the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
> ```
>
> The install completed successfully, but the wireless isn't seeing my
>   wireless signal. More investigation indicated that Dell used a utility
>   name a Quickset utility to turn on / off the radio on the card. I
>   received a comment to my question that took me to:
>
> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access
>
> I then went to the FAQ from that page and there was a question:
>
> Q: The radio-enable-button on my laptop does not work.
>
> A: You have to enable RF-kill support in the kernel configuration. The
>   config options you have to enable are: `CONFIG_RFKILL`,
>   `CONFIG_RFKILL_INPUT`, `CONFIG_INPUT_POLLDEV`.
>
> Before proceeding I would like to do as the answer indicates, but I do
>   not know what the command string would look like.

Answering my own question. After researching the comment on my question, I was lead to this being a possible solution from the developer page regarding my wifi card. I am new at this. What do I type in the terminal to satisfy the items below. I have loaded the b43legacy drivers. The wireless is enabled and ON in the BIOS. The wireless does not seem to see any signals. I am guessing, the RF is off and needs to be turned on.

You have to enable RF-kill support in the kernel configuration. The config options you have to enable are: `CONFIG_RFKILL`, `CONFIG_RFKILL_INPUT`, `CONFIG_INPUT_POLLDEV`

Comment: @Zanna Looks more like a valid self-answer to me

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 on a Inspiron 5437.

- Realtek and Atheros is what matters for wireless.

run

```
sudo lshw # you will find your specs
```

You are after the *-network (sections)

Realtek:

*r8168-dkms - dkms source for the r8168 network driver*

Atheros:

*collectd-core - statistics collection and monitoring daemon (core system)*

Realtek is straightforward and the Atheros pack covers quite a lot of situations.

```
sudo apt-cache show collectd-core
```

[Ctrl]+[up] and [down] to see Atheros wireless entries

I would first--

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

--than

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms && sudo apt-get install collected-core
```

-#Open GEdit and take note of recommended packs, than take a look at what may interest you.#